# My Android singleton gets destroyed

Tags: java, android, singleton

I´ll do appreciate som light with the following problem.
 I am writing an android application that comunicates with a remote server, the application stars with a login scrren, after the user login i want some important ionformation to get reachable through the entire appLication, user information, the department in wich the user works etc,
  After reading about the best to achieve that I decided to use a singleton by extending the application class. Here is an example.

```
public class UsuarioCustom extends Application {

 private Usuario usuario;
 private Location posicionActual;   
 private Delegacion department;
 private RutaCustom rutaActual;          

     //getters and setters ....
}
```

One of the requirements of the applications is that have to send the current location of the user ever 10 minutes so this application needs  to keep running for a log while.

I am testing the appication and from time to time crashed showing the window the application has stoped.

I debuged de application and I realized the at some point android set my  singleton class to null. I read on the web that this is a common issue in android...

For example If i start my application then with the phone to airplane mode and then come back to my app y can see how my singleton is null.

I have read on the web about singleton classes on android, some people says that is better to use a servive but seems like the oficial android sdk documentation lacks some useful information here.

**I am thinking about saving the information on sqllite so every time i want to use my singleton class i check if is null, if so i reload it again from sql litte.**

Can someone give some nice tips about the best way to deal with that probem??.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Give more code cause here we don't see your singleton

Comment: djechlin I don´t know what you men all my questons are already closed, unfortunately i can not vote up the answers.

Comment: Jaumard, the only piece of code shows how I created my singleton class, by extending the application class,

Comment: Any useful tip? didn't anyone have to deal with singleton classes killed by android???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web , I finally decided to save the important imformation on the sqllite. Seems like in an Android enviroment u can not trust that u can save data on memory for a long time, soon or later Android will delete the informatión even if you create a singleton by extending the Application class.